# Should a digital agency use one EC2 instance for multiple client websites or use one EC2 per client website

Tags: amazon-aws, amazon-ec2

I've recently started a digital agency of my own after working at them for a number of years and looking into using AWS for my website and email hosting needs.

From looking at AWS's website, I can see that hosting emails for my clients is easily achievable by using their AWS WorkMail product. However, I'm struggling to see what the best solution is for hosting multiple websites of various sizes and traffic for each of my clients.

Taking cost, maintenance, individual scalability and monitoring into consideration, is it best to create one powerful EC2 instance and host multiple websites on it or is best to create an EC2 for each of my clients' websites regardless of how big the website is?

I'm seeing so many articles on 'how to host multiple websites on one EC2' which is what's confusing me but I can't see the value of this unless a business has a number of small websites under its roof.

Comment: Welcome to Webmasters!

Comment: This post is old but would love to here what you ended up doing?
Especially where / if you had multiple clients who all need an SSL cert